# Mysql to mssql Data Load failure - High number of rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package connecting to a MYSQL system and fetching data within a table. As a One time Load, i need to fetch 570,000,000 rows into this table. This package keeps timing out and currently, i have 0 records imported.

I tried breaking it into 10 chunks of 57,000,000 each using value in an incremental id column. it does'nt help. How can i find an optimum count of data that can be imported in one go.

How can I import all rows efficiently, given an Id field which is auto- increment? It is only a one time operation.

Comment: Try 50,000,000.  Try 20,000,000.  Try 10,000,000.  Eventually you'll find one that works.  Unfortunately, whatever is causing the problem is probably highly dependent on your hardware, software, and network, so I'm guessing there is not general answer.

Comment: Yes, currently trial and error is my only resort :(

Comment: . . I would be inclined to work my way up -- if the successes may come back faster than the failures.  Also, setting the recovery model to "simple" might help performance, if you are using a mechanism where they would be logged.

Comment: Oh.. currently it is 'Full'. Will change to simple.

Comment: Have you set a batch size in the destination component? The default (none) will send all rows at once. Try something like 1000, 5000 rows and work up or down to achieve the best performance. Small batch sizes result in smaller transactions but more round trips.